# MailChimp merge tag for Group membership

Tags: merge, tags, mailchimp

I would like to send a confirmation email to my subscribers showing the groups(s) to which they belong.

Does MailChimp have a merge tag for that?

If not, is there any other way that I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use conditional statements and the INTERESTED tag. Such as:

```
*|INTERESTED:Hobby:Music|*
You are subscribed to the music group
*|END:INTERESTED|*

*|INTERESTED:Hobby:Swimming|*
You are subscribed to the swimming group
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

You can also do more complex nested statements such as:

```
*|INTERESTED:Cities:New York|*
    *|INTERESTED:Hobby:Music|*
    You are subscribed to the music group in New York
    *|ELSE:|*
    You are subscribed to the group in New York
    *|END:INTERESTED|*
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

You can use this within the body of the text, the footer or in an URL for click tracking.

More info here: http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this sooner.  What you have suggested will show content depending on what groups they subscribe to. What I want to do is to show them the groups to which they are subscribed and allow them to change them if they so wish.  I have been trying with the Profile Update form, but that only shows the first and last names and email address, even though I have edited the update form to include the groups.